# I can't get recipient's number in delivery status message

Tags: sms, at-command

I'm trying to send a text message via AT commands and Siemens TC35
I can send an SMS but when I receive the status of delivery I receive it without the recipient's number. I do not know when the report is sent to me.

```
 AT+CMGF=1
 AT+CSMP =49,167,0,0
 AT+CMGS="number"
 message ctr+z

 modem response:
 +CMGS: 98
     OK
```

When i'm listing messages by:

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"
```

I get:
    +CMGL: 7,"REC UNREAD",6,98,,,"19/05/14,17:27:22+08","19/05/14,17:27:24+08",0

I don't now why a i get only 6 instead number of recipient.

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this by memory...

For every successfully SMS send, you get a codeID that you have to store, manage and relate to any message status that might come through.

The message status will have the codeID and not the recipient number. That way you can send several SMS to a number and for each message sent you get a distinct** identifiable code to relate to the message status.

In your example is the codeID returned is 98.

** I haven't worked with SMS a long time, but I seem to recall that the size of this field is small, 0-99 or 0-999 I think,  and is a ciclic ID, so if a massive number of SMS is sent it's possible that the ID will repeat for the same number, so keep that in mind in your code